# Error inserting into custom table - Object of class wpdb could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql

Getting the above error when trying to insert into custom table .I am unable to find out what is the cause of the error.

The error comes at line 17. Any help is greatly appreicated.

The code is below:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "wp-load.php";
require_once "dbconfig.php";

global $wpdb, $current_user;
$current_user=wp_get_current_user();
$current_username = $current_user->user_login;
$table_name='persons';
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name= $_POST['last_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$telephone=$_POST['telephone'];

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
"
 INSERT INTO $wpdb->$table_name
( first_name, last_name, email,telephone,user_name)
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s,%s,%s )
",
$first_name,$last_name,$email,$telephone,$current_username
) );
```

Comment: Seems like there's a typo here: `$wpdb->$table_name` in the query.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpdb->$table_name` is not a valid table name. Use `$table_name`

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
"
 INSERT INTO $wpdb->$table_name
( first_name, last_name, email,telephone,user_name)
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s,%s,%s )
",
$first_name,$last_name,$email,$telephone,$current_username
) );
```

should be

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
"
 INSERT INTO $table_name
( first_name, last_name, email,telephone,user_name)
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s,%s,%s )
",
$first_name,$last_name,$email,$telephone,$current_username
) );
```